# Making a horizontal list take up full div width, while vertical lists take up minimum width and pad the rest

Tags: html, css

I have an element with a pre-determined width, and within that element I have 1 or more lists.  Each list will have a class defining whether it is horizontal or vertical.

The horizontal list needs to span the full width of the div, but center the list items.  When try to make the list items equally share the space given to them rather than just centering, I get no results - I don't have to worry about horizontal overflow, since I can just make a second horizontal list if I need to.
The same thing is true for when I try to do this with the vertical lists.

```css
.c {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  background: orange;
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.h {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}

.h li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}

.v {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.v li {
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <ol class="h">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="v">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="v">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**And I want to end up with this:**

[image: This is the best I could get with Paint, but notice how these elements are now properly spaced and expanded.]

How do I get the horizontal items to self-pad, as well as the vertical lists?  I'm looking for results without the use of tables, display: table (etc), and flex, if possible.  It doesn't matter if extra space is filled in with padding or margin to me.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `display: flex;`? It would be the nicest solution to your problem...

Comment: Mostly because of potential compatibility issues, I don't have bright users.  In the end I suppose I could use flex, since it really is what I need, but I'd need a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options;

1. Make CSS rules for all the possible amounts of horizontal list elements
2. Use tables
3. Use JavaScript
4. Use flex

I can write examples for all those options, or just the option(s) you'd like.

Comment: Not really.  It's the spacing between the items that I need to fix.  I essentially need each item to take up the same amount of space within the given div or list.  Example: The list items would each take up 1/3 of the width, and if there were 4, 1/4 of the width each.

Comment: How about percentage widths? . h li{width:33%} for 1/3 and .h li{width:25%} for 1/4, etc.

Comment: That would work if it were strictly set numbers and lengths, but otherwise that's not scalable or good css.  The number of items and length of the items in the list can change drastically.

Comment: Afaik, you have 4 options. 1.) make css rules for all possible cases 2.) use tables 3.) use Javascript 4.) use flex.  I can write examples for all cases or the option you'd like.

Comment: I'm assuming "use javascript" is just computing padding and width at runtime?  Curious what you mean by "Make css rules for all possible cases" though

Comment: Yes, by using JS, I mean that you'd get the amount of list elements in each horizontal list, and calculate the dimensions/margins for each of them based on that. And by making CSS rules for all possible cases I mean that if you have 2 elements, youd make a rule for `.h li{width:50%}`, 3 elements `.h li{width:33%}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This div container .c has 90% width.
So the properties are being inherited by the other classes it seems.

You also have the issue of the yellow background not covering the other classes.

The changes I made were creating a new class to wrap around everything to make sure it all has the yellow background and I also wrapped your .c div around the other 2 classes instead and changed the .h class to display inline-block, this means you can set the height and width of the element while keeping it inline, I set the width to 100% and aligned the text to centre.

```css
.d {
  background: orange;
}

.c {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.h {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.h li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;

}

.v {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.v li {
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
  <div class="d">
  <ol class="h">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
<div class="c">
  <ol class="v">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="v">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Line</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't really approach my question at all.  I'm going to try and make a picture of what I'm going for since apparently its not clear.